# Django: How to access the label and checkbox separately in CheckboxSelectMultiple?

Tags: html, django

I would like to make each checkbox into a toggle button. However, Django renders the checkboxes automatically as a list. I couldn't any way to make them separate.

this is what I have right now:

```
<div class="column">
    <div id="filters">
        {% for field in filter_form %}
            <div class="filter_category">
                {% for checkbox in field %}
                    {{ checkbox }}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

I would like something such as this so I have more flexibility with what I can do.

```
<div class="column">
    <div id="filters">
        {% for field in filter_form %}
            <div class="filter_category">
                {% for checkbox in field %}
                    {{ checkbox.label }}{{ checkbox.tag }}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

This is my form class, the constructor simply populates the choices for each of the fields

```
class Class_filters_form(forms.Form):

    subject_code = forms.CharField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"checked": ""}))
    subject_level_CLB = forms.CharField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"checked": ""}))
    subject_level_CEFR = forms.CharField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"checked": ""}))
    time_start = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"checked": ""}))
    campus = forms.CharField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=Data_room.CAMPUS_CHOICE, attrs={"checked": ""}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): ...
```

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4592